# PictureBox image appears differently on different computers

Tags: .net

What I see:

[image]

What the customer sees:

[image]

The images themselves are different sizes due to different resolutions at the time the screenshots were taken. The issue is that he see the logo as cutoff by the text and button.

I have tried many different resolutions on my computer and the image always looks correct. He has tried many different resolutions on his computer and the image is always cutoff.

Designer code:

```
Me.PictureBox1.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("PictureBox1.Image"), System.Drawing.Image)
Me.PictureBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
Me.PictureBox1.Name = "PictureBox1"
Me.PictureBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 56)
Me.PictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
Me.PictureBox1.TabIndex = 0
Me.PictureBox1.TabStop = False
```

Comment: It looks like the OS text scaling is set to 125% or 150% on your computer. That affects all forms.

Comment: Try setting [AutoScaleMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `Dpi` or `None` also check [AutoScaleMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Enigmativity, you are correct that that is the root cause. Good catch. I changed the text size on my computer long ago and totally forgot about it. Perhaps one of the other solutions will actually allow the image to display properly under any text scaling, but for now I'll just make sure I design my forms with 100% scaling.

Comment: The form auto-scaled just fine.  But not the PictureBox, you prevented it from scaling properly by using PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize.  The only true solution is to use different artwork, Q&D fix is to use PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom.

Comment: Thanks, Han, I will test this out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the OS text scaling is set to 125% or 150% on your computer. That affects all the layout of forms.